# On_member_join and on_member_leave not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've got on_member_joion and on_member_leave code, and it's not working, this is my code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
botprefix = ","
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = botprefix, case_insensitive=True, intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_mmember_join(member):
  channel = bot.get_channel(803616331835899934)
  await channel.send(f"Witaj {member.mention} na serwerze **Pogaduszki!**")

@bot.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
  channel = bot.get_channel(803616331835899934)
  await channel.send(f"Żegnamy {member.mention}, mamy nadzieję że do nas wrócisz")
```

And this code is not working, there are no errors, can anyone help please??
PS: I'm using https://replit.com

Comment: Have you enabled intents in the discord developer portal?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled and bot still not responding

Comment: Not sure if its related to this typo `def on_mmember_join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error with your `join` event.
It should be `on_member_join` and not `on_mmember_join`.

Also, you should consider not using `on_member_leave` but `on_member_remove`.

**Your full code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = bot.get_channel(803616331835899934)
  await channel.send(f "Witaj {member.mention} na serwerze **Pogaduszki!**")

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  channel = bot.get_channel(803616331835899934)
  await channel.send(f "Żegnamy {member.mention}, mamy nadzieję że do nas wrócisz")
```

*Also have a look at the docs for more:*
[on_member_remove()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove)